# Relocate load address of main module IDA

Tags: ida

is it possible when performing static analysis with IDA to change the default load address of the module (ie 0x00400000 in most cases depending on PE preferences) ? I think I read a book on IDA 1 year ago which taught me how to, however with googling around and browsing in IDA i didn't find anything.

Comment: Edit-->Segments-->Rebase program menu item in Ida.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Passing confirmed answer from the comment:

See Edit-->Segments-->Rebase program menu item in Ida.
Online help on this menu item is [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1408.shtml).